# Ruby on Rails. Predefined data installation in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new with Ruby on Rails and have some issues with it. I am writing my application on Rails and i have to install some pre-defined data in my Database to use it in my application. This data is read-only and never change (for example users and roles. There are no use cases to create new users and roles).

So i have to install this data when my application runs first time. I tried to use Migrations to solve this problem, but my manager told me that it is not a right way, cause migrations are usually used to define DB structure changes and not to install any data in DB.

Can you please help me and tell better way to install my pre-defined data using Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Please see [this section](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data) in the Rails guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to achieve this using the [`seeds` functionality](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data):

> To add initial data after a database is created, Rails has a built-in 'seeds' feature that makes the process quick and easy. This is especially useful when reloading the database frequently in development and test environments. It's easy to get started with this feature: just fill up `db/seeds.rb` with some Ruby code, and run `rake db:seed`:

```
#db/seeds.rb
User.create name: "test", description: "info"

$ rake db:seed
```

--

If you wanted *static* data, you'll be able to use a gem such as the [`config` gem](https://github.com/railsconfig/config) -- which gives you the ability to allocate values in `config/settings.yml`:

[image]

This data is then accessible as `Settings.company...`

Answer (score 1):

You should use [seeds](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data). See this [rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data)

You could also look at [Dibber](https://github.com/reggieb/Dibber), that allows you to define your seeds via YML files.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking to do is seed the database. Rails comes with a `db/seeds.rb` that you can use to do this. There are also gems such as [seed-fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu) that you could use.

Here is a [short tutorial](http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html) on seeding a database in Rails.